# Join Mysql statement issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have two form drop-downs that capture two IDs, which relate to PKs from a table named `nodes`.

I want to delete those two nodes from within another table, named `relationships`.

So after I gather the 2 node IDs, I'm trying to delete the one node that is in a relationship with the other node.

In my relationship I have the `id` and `goingto` both as nodes, however only `id` is an FK and the other one isn't.

So how do I delete that if it is in a relationship?

Here is my attempt

```
$goingto = $_POST['id_one']; //get from form both from id in nodes
$id = $_POST['idtwo']; //get from form both from id in nodes

mysql> DELETE from relationships where $id = $goingto;
```

Here is my table structure:

```
nodes                 relationships                      
-----                 -------------
id int(11),           id int(11),
name varchar(35),     goingto int(11), //this is the destinationnode from the id relation 
color varchar(7),     data varchar(0) null
type varchar (12),    Foreign key (id) references nodes(id)
Primary key (id)       

engine = innodb
```

Comment: 1. Are `id_one` and `id_two` guaranteed to relate to each other via the `relationships` table?  2. If so, do we know if it is `id_one` `goingto` `id_two`, or will it be `id_two` `goingto` `id_one`?  Or will there be _two_ relationship records for this - ie one in each direction?  3. Do you want to delete the `nodes` themselves (along with all associated `relationships` for those nodes), or just the `relationships` that exist _between_ them? 4. Perhaps it'd just be easier to post the assignment/exam question in full, rather than stripping out the pertinent details.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this is what you mean:

DELETE from relationships where id = $id and goingto = $goingto;

Comment: yeah thats what I exactly what I mean.